# Using If/Then/Else in a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I've got a stored procedure that I'm passing values to from a C# app.  What I need to do is filter the data based on a selection from a dropdown in the app.  So, I've got something like this:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[usp_AllCompletedTasks]
    @StDate smalldatetime,
    @EnDate smalldatetime,
    @xRole int,
    @xFunction int
AS

BEGIN

declare @StrDate smalldatetime,
        @EndDate smalldatetime,
        @MyRole int,
        @MyFunction int

set @StrDate = @StDate 
set @EndDate = @EnDate 
set @MyRole = @xRole 
set @MyFunction = @xFunction 

SELECT 
   ... Some Fields    
FROM MyTable    

WHERE   
    AND Work_Start >= DATEADD(dd,0,DATEDIFF(dd,0,@strDate))
    AND Work_End <= DATEADD(dd,1,DATEDIFF(dd,0,@endDate))
    AND ROLE_ID = @MyRole
    AND FUNCTION_ID = @MyFunction
```

Now, what the powers upstairs decided is that they want a "Select All" option in the Role and Function dropdowns.  So, what I did was put a Select All option in on the C# side and set the value to 0.

What I figured I'd do is change the ROLE_ID and FUNCTION_ID     filters to use **LIKE** instead of **=**, and then use an If/Then/Else statement at the top to say, "If the value of @MyRole is 0, change it to &" or something.

Is this even possible in SQL Server?

Comment: [Yes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `ROLE_ID` and `FUNCTION_ID` columns are integers you have to convert them to one of the character types in order to use the `LIKE`operator.

I suggest that when the 'Select All' is selected pass the `NULL` 'value' to the desired parameter and rewrite your conditions like this:

```
AND (@MyRole IS NULL OR ROLE_ID = @MyRole)
AND (@MyFunction IS NULL OR FUNCTION_ID = @MyFunction)
```

**EDIT (+note)**
Do not use a specific value as the 'not specified value', you have that symbol already in SQL: the `NULL`.

Comment: Any idea on how to get this to happen in C#?  If I run this in SQL Server it works like a champ: **EXEC dbo.usp_mos_DetailComp '5/27/2014', '6/4/2014', NULL, NULL**.  If I use this in C# to add the Select All, it errors out: **cboFunction.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select All", ""));**

Comment: Nevermind.  I set the list item in C# to be equal to 0 as it had been, and then just changed **AND (@MyRole IS NULL OR ROLE_ID = @MyRole)** to **AND (@MyRole = 0 OR ROLE_ID = @MyRole)** (and the same with Function) and it worked perfectly.  Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome! By the way, you can use the `DBNull.Value` in C# to pass `NULL` to queries (and SPs)

Answer (score 0):

If I follow correctly, you can get what you want by just adding another condition to your `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE   
    AND Work_Start >= DATEADD(dd,0,DATEDIFF(dd,0,@strDate))
    AND Work_End <= DATEADD(dd,1,DATEDIFF(dd,0,@endDate))
    AND ((ROLE_ID = @MyRole AND FUNCTION_ID = @MyFunction)
         OR (@MyRole = 0 AND @MyFunction = 0))
```

If your variables are `0` then the results are not filtered by `ROLE_ID` and `FUNCTION_ID`, if they need to be evaluated independently then you would have to add additional logic.

Comment: Both `@MyRole` and `@MyFunction` should be 0 or non 0. When one of them is 0 and the another is not, the condition will fail.

Comment: @Pred Agreed, that's what I was getting at in the note at the end, it depends on if OP wants them evaluated together or not, is the `SELECT ALL` option available to each variable or is it an overarching option. Don't think that's clear in the question.

Answer (score 0):

If  Select All is selected then the below ID as NULL and modify your query as shown below.

AND ROLE_ID =ISNULL(@MyRole, ROLE_ID)

```
AND FUNCTION_ID =ISNULL(@MyFunction, FUNCTION_ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can have a string variable, set the select statement you want to it depending on your parameter values in a if then statement and then execute the sqlString

Answer (score 0):

By the way, to answer my original question (now that I see this one has over 1,000 hits), I've since discovered that something like this in Access:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, TelephoneNumber, 
     IIf(IsNull(TelephoneInstructions),"Any time",
     TelephoneInstructions) AS [When to Contact]
FROM db1.ContactInfo;
```

would be written something like this in SQL Server:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, TelephoneNumber, "When to Contact" = 
     CASE
          WHEN TelephoneInstructions IS NULL THEN 'Any time'
          ELSE TelephoneInstructions
     END
FROM db1.ContactInfo;
```